# Принципы русской орфографии

Tags: орфография

проверьте, пожалуйста, правильно ли? Может ли одно слово относится к двум принципам? 
традиционные: жизнь, настежь, лишь, видишь, пишешь, ешь, красного, волнующего, соберу, собираю, постелю,прочь, шить. морфологический: вскачь, бедняжка, высота, сбить, синего. фонетический: молодость, подсказать, роспись, развалить, поступить, раздать, расписать, изыскать, безымянный, подытожить.

Comment: Судя по тому, что 9 часов нет никакого ответа, это не я такой тупой,а всем требуется пояснение к вопросу от его автора.

Comment: Просто, если это школьное задание, то мы отвечанием на них только при наличии собственного варианта ответа. А если нет, то, думаю, ответ появится.

Answer (score 1):

Традиционные написания: жизнь, настежь, лишь, , прочь: вскачь красного, волнующего, соберу, собираю, постелю, синего, шить.

морфологический :видишь, пишешь, ешь, бедняжка, высота, сбить,. молодость подсказать поступить

фонетический: роспись, развалить, , раздать, расписать, изыскать, безымянный, подытожить.

Comment: Правда, чередования некоторые учёные относят к фонетическому:соберу, собираю, постелю